# OpenVPN - Can not Connect to Server (Unrecognized option or missing parameter(s))

Tags: openvpn

I have a problem connecting to a VPN-Server, and I cant figure out why.
The server is working fine on my Phone, as well as it did on Windows before I changed to Linux.

When I try to connect via

```
openvpn --config cfg.ovpn
```

I get the following error:

```
Options error: Unrecognized option or missing parameter(s) in saveyourprivacy.ovpn:26: tls-version-min (2.3.2)
Use --help for more information.
```

My OpenVPN version is

```
OpenVPN 2.3.2 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [eurephia] [MH] [IPv6] built on Dec  1 201
```

(Installed via apt-get openvpn)

This is the saveyourprivacy.ovpn file:

```
##############################################
# SaveYourPrivacy VPN                        #
# vpn.saveyourprivacy.net                    #
##############################################

client
dev tun
remote-random

<connection>
remote 185.100.86.100 1194 udp
</connection>

<connection>
remote 185.100.86.100 8080 tcp
</connection>
#ZEILE17
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
link-mtu 1350

ca ca.crt
cert client.crt
key client.key

remote-cert-tls server
verify-x509-name vpn.saveyourprivacy.net name
tls-version-min 1.2

tls-auth ta.key 1

cipher AES-256-CBC
auth SHA512

comp-lzo

verb 0
```

EDIT:
If I comment out

```
#tls-version-min 1.2
```

The command does not exit, but does not give me any response whatsoever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the error about an unrecognized configuration option, the version of OpenVPN client installed on your system may not have the capability to use the `tls-version-min 1.2` option - not all OpenVPN clients support it, I believe.  You may have to edit the `.ovpn` to remove that item from the file, and then try and connect.  (From what I can tell, 2.3.2 is older than when `tls-version-min` was introduced...)

Your other alternative is to try and compile the latest OpenVPN client for your computer yourself, but there's NO guarantees that'll work as you expect it to.  Ever.

Comment: I tried that, now the client does just nothing. 
I also tried to compile the latest ovpn client from the sources, but that somehow did not work because of some compiler issues.

Comment: @M.Reyes "Compiler Issues" is vague; but the problem is you're stuck needing a newer version of the openvpn client, likely.  Especially if they are enforcing TLS 1.2